# Pandas pivot table with hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I need to create a pivot table. My data frame has the following structure:

[image: data structure]

```
print (df)
  company team person project unit start   end  num
0     ABC  Dev   John     pr1   BE  date  date    3
1     ABC  Dev    Tim     pr1   FE  date  date    4
2     ABC  Dev  James     pr2   FE  date  date    3
```

---

I tried to use the following pandas functions:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,
                index=["company","team","person"],
                columns=["project", 'unit'],
                values=["start","end","num"],
                aggfunc={"start": np.min,
                       "end": np.max ,
                       "num": np.sum},
                fill_value=0)
table.columns = table.columns.swaplevel(2, 0).swaplevel(1, 0)
```

Data were transformed into following pivot table:

[image: pivot]

And I ended up with desired data outcome, but formating is an issue. I’d like the data frame to be in the following format:

[image: desired ourcome]

Is there a way to transform columns into hierarchical columns with the pandas pivot table function?

Comment: [Please don't upload images of data or code on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and change order by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with list:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,
                index=["company","team","person"],
                columns=["project", 'unit'],
                values=["start","end","num"],
                aggfunc={"start": np.min,
                       "end": np.max ,
                       "num": np.sum},
                fill_value=0)

vals = ['start','end','num']
table = table.reorder_levels([1,2,0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).reindex(vals, level=2, axis=1)
print (table)
project               pr1                             pr2          
unit                   BE              FE              FE          
                    start   end num start   end num start   end num
company team person                                                
ABC     Dev  James      0     0   0     0     0   0  date  date   3
             John    date  date   3     0     0   0     0     0   0
             Tim        0     0   0  date  date   4     0     0   0
```